Docker containers not running application after Angular Upgrade
Dockerfile
FROM node:18.20-alpine3.19 As build

WORKDIR /usr/local/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./ /usr/local/app/

ARG ENVIRONMENT=production

# Extract commit ID
ARG COMMIT_ID
RUN echo "Commit ID: $COMMIT_ID" > commit.txt

RUN echo 'Environment:' ${ENVIRONMENT}

RUN npm run build -- --configuration=${ENVIRONMENT}

### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.25.3-alpine

COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist/my-app-client /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/commit.txt /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80


server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}

Whenever I run the container and visit the host I get:
Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.

Notes:

Upgraded from Angular 16 -> 18
Build is using @angular-devkit/build-angular:application, before was "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser". Not sure if I can use the old one but
outputPath is dist/my-app-client in Angular.json


This question is similar to: My dockerfile for deploying my angular app doesnt start the app using a web server either nodeJs or nginx. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The folder structure is different with the application builder. For more information, see the linked question & answer.
